For beginners: Module not Found but Requirement already satisfied example using PyPDF2
This post has two parts:

To help beginners starting up with creating virtual environments and installing packages for Python in Visual studio Code (I am on MACOS however should be able to follow on windows)

A question of how to Resolve when a module is missing despite the requirement already being satisfied (i.e. already installed)


VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENTS AND PACKAGE INSTILLATION VIA PIP3
Creating New Virtual Environment (.VIRTUAL_ENV)

change directory to location you want to create virtual environment (cd)
python3 - m venv .VIRTUAL_ENV (or whatever name you wish to call it)


Activating Virtual Environment:

Copy Path of virtual environment


Activate it (source /bin/activate.)



Check packages in Virtual Environment (Empty as nothing installed)

Selecting Interpreter

Print hello to make sure all is working okay.

Demoing Expected Behaviour using numpy

numpy not yet installed.



pip3 install numpy


And we can see the numpy package(s) are added to the library
same again with pip3 install matplotlib.

Alot more packages are being added this time but successfully installs without issue.
Checking both installed okay:

Now for PyPDF2:
Before installing:

pip3 install PyPDF2

Package appears to install correctly, yellow squiggle disappears all seems okay.
But when I run the script now:

and again just to confirm that is the case:

Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF2 in ./.VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.13/site-packages

final checks:
pip3 show PyPDF2

pip3 list

If anyone can assist on why this is the case it would be appreciated.
I have looked at the following post however the suggestions here either dont work or are for windows:
"no module named PyPDF2" error

Recommendation: Do not use words like python as the name of your file, nor library names. They generate silent errors

Haha yes thank you, I did realise but I was already too deep with the screenshots. I think for this purpose it's okay but yes I agree.

You can show what comes up in TERMINAL tab when you get the error.

Currently my settings in visual studio are modified to show in the output tab. But let me modify this and get back to you

oh noes please don't spamshot, describe what you're doing and post your code as plain text

@folengateis to be fair the code is provided in the headings. This is for absolute beginners as I see a lot online people struggling to install modules.

to be fair to whom? this not an image board. the philosophy behind your question is at the exact opposite of stack overflow's: we don't want to condescendingly take people by the hand, this is not a tutorial website.

do you seriously think that an absolute beginner will google "For beginners: Module not Found but Requirement already satisfied example using PyPDF2" when their actual problem is that they can't install pygame?

lol, Yes I do think an absolute beginner will google 'Module not Found but Requirement already satisfied' and this will come up. PyPDF2 is as it says.. for example. And no it's not a tutorial website, but I have an issue that I think many would find common using PyPDF2, Pygame or any other module. The question isn't about PyPDF2..

Please refer to the same issue on GitHub: No module named 'PyPDF2' .

pypdf2 is deprecated, replaced by pypdf.

https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/456#issuecomment-2071363332

While I agree that PyPDF2 should be replaced by the maintained pypdf, how does this issue resolve the question? The screenshots show that both packages are installed, thus it generally seems like a general environment issue.

@epR8GaYuh Thank you. Although useful to know about pypdf2, you have nailed the actual question.

What if you compile the py file manually on the command line?

Selecting Run python file rather than just run, it runs without issue in terminal. It seems that the issue is with the environment. I have done a full reinstall of visual studio which seems to have fixed some issues. Odd that PyPDF2 still shows as requirement satisfied despite being installed but as you've pointed out it is depreciated. pypdf is working though, initially this appeared to have the same issue.

actually just tested with pyPDF2... and now this works too. Definitely some issue with the visual studio setup.

This seems like a problem with VSCode not being set to the correct Python interpreter.
Also, have you tried reactivating the virtual environment?
Check your current pip list to make sure the package is installed in the correct environment.
Update: I have created a test script with pretty much the same way as you did. And the code works. Ensure where your Python executive is and run via the command line. See the screenshots below.





Hi there, You can see from the screenshots that it is indeed present. As per your suggestion though I have added an additional 2 screenshots at the end showing indeed that they are present in the list. Also Just reactivated virtual environment and no change. Finally Python interpreter seems to be correct. Selecting others, the other modules become missing. This interpreter things seem okay for all modules except PyPDF2.

screenshots for code is bad practice, please don't. if you think people might want to use or test your code then don't prevent them from doing so: plain text is the only way to easily copy-paste it
